# In T-SQL, why is like operator not working for a variable but works for a literal?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here is the script:

First script:

```
declare @a char(10) = 'AA%'
declare @b char(10) = 'AA001'

if @b LIKE @a 
     print 'Equals' 
else 
begin 
     print 'Not equals' 
end
```

It prints:

```
Not Equals
```

I was expecting it to print `Equals`. But the script below which does not use `@a` in the condition:

Second script:

```
declare @a char(10) = 'AA%'
declare @b char(10) = 'AA001'

if @b LIKE 'AA%' 
    print 'Equals' 
else 
begin 
    print 'Not equals' 
end
```

prints

```
Equals
```

So why does the first script consider them not-equal but the second script consider them equal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is actually simple but this is a *big gotcha*: It is because of the `char` type.

If we were to print out the 2 variables:

```
print @a
print @b
```

The output would be (dots mean empty space):

```
AA%.......       
AA001.....
```

So the first query does a `like` on the two variables and the trailing blanks make it not equal because according to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql), and logically speaking, the trailing blanks (empty spaces) are significant:

> If a comparison in a query is to return all rows with the string LIKE 'abc' (abc without a space), all rows that start with abc and have zero or more trailing blanks are returned. +
>   A string comparison using a pattern that contains char and varchar data may not pass a LIKE comparison because of how the data is stored.

**Second Query**

The second query has the literal `AA%` whose implicit type is `varchar` and since `AA001` (whose type is `char`) will be like `AA%`, it prints *Equals*. To reaffirm that the type of the literal is `varchar`, I used this query:

```
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY('AA%', 'BaseType')
```

which returns *varchar*.

---

**Some More Info**

Here is some more examples from MSDN for further clarity:

The following example passes a local char variable to a stored procedure and then uses pattern matching to find all of the employees whose last names start with a specified set of characters.

```
-- Uses AdventureWorks  

CREATE PROCEDURE FindEmployee @EmpLName char(20)  
AS  
SELECT @EmpLName = RTRIM(@EmpLName) + '%';  
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName, a.City  
FROM Person.Person p JOIN Person.Address a ON p.BusinessEntityID = a.AddressID  
WHERE p.LastName LIKE @EmpLName;  
GO  
EXEC FindEmployee @EmpLName = 'Barb';  
GO
```

In the `FindEmployee` procedure, no rows are returned because the char variable (`@EmpLName`) contains trailing blanks whenever the name contains fewer than 20 characters. Because the `LastName` column is varchar, there are no trailing blanks. This procedure fails because the trailing blanks are significant.
However, the following example succeeds because trailing blanks are not added to a varchar variable.

-- Uses AdventureWorks

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FindEmployee @EmpLName varchar(20)  
AS  
SELECT @EmpLName = RTRIM(@EmpLName) + '%';  
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName, a.City  
FROM Person.Person p JOIN Person.Address a ON p.BusinessEntityID = a.AddressID  
WHERE p.LastName LIKE @EmpLName;  
GO  
EXEC FindEmployee @EmpLName = 'Barb';
```

Here is the result set:

```
FirstName LastName City
---------- -------------------- ---------------
Angela Barbariol Snohomish
David Barber Snohomish
(2 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: I just started to think about a strange collation issue (doubled `AA` has some special meaning in a rare scandinavian characters set), but this is a great catch! +1